# Synchronizing Postman scripts

Tags: postman

I want to post a comment, set an environment variable from the response, and then delete this comment using the variable in my 'DELETE' request. I have such script in the "Test" tab of my "POST" request:

```
const response = pm.response.json();

pm.environment.set('CommentId', response.comment.id);

eval(environment.deleteComment) ();
```

This is the object from which I want to get the "id" property

```
    {
"comment": {
    "id": 3263,
    "createdAt": "2022-01-11T21:32:01.599Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-01-11T21:32:01.599Z",
    "body": "Debitis et asperiores.",
    "author": {
        "username": "Natalia_Gislason31",
        "bio": null,
        "image": "https://api.realworld.io/images/smiley-cyrus.jpeg",
        "following": false
    }
}
```

}

But "pm.response.json()" tries to parse the "DELETE" method response instead which is called by eval, and I get this error "JSONError: No data, empty input at 1:1". Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using pm.response.text() instead of pm.response.json()

(That is - assuming that the data returned by your endpoint isn't actually json. I don't see why else you'd be getting a json parse exception)

This portion of the docs goes over the pm.response functions available:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#scripting-with-response-data

Comment: I'm getting JSON object: 
{
    "comment": {
        "id": 3263,
        "createdAt": "2022-01-11T21:32:01.599Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-01-11T21:32:01.599Z",
        "body": "Debitis et asperiores.",
        "author": {
            "username": "Natalia_Gislason31",
            "bio": null,
            "image": "https://api.realworld.io/images/smiley-cyrus.jpeg",
            "following": false
        }
    }
}

Comment: And I need to get id from it, set it as an environment variable and use this variable in the "DELETE" request which is called by eval

Comment: But instead of parsing this object, pm. is trying to pars the response after "DELETE" which is empty